# Xamarin Forms: Alignment issue with HorizontalOptions property

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, chat

I have implemented a chat UI in my project. Send messages are showing on the left side and received messages are showing on the right side.

For showing messages on the left and right side I have created a new variable on the model class like below:

```
private LayoutOptions horizontalOptions;
public LayoutOptions HorizontalOptions
{
    get => horizontalOptions;
    set
    {
        horizontalOptions = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(horizontalOptions));
    }
}
```

Based on the username value I set the `HorizontalOptions` value like below:

```
string myUsername = "myusername";
string tweetUser = username in the message;
if (myUsername == tweetUser)
{
    tweet.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
}
else
{
    tweet.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
}
```

This feature is working fine when loading messages initially. When I send a new message the alignment is breaking. Some messages are moving to the left and some are moving to the right. If I tap the editor after sending a new message the alignment issues are going. Don't know what is the real issue behind this.

I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1agUL3VZV-1kMGsgBLZ5Xc7pSFxxX2uvb/view?usp=sharing).

Also, one screen recorder video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oQEQRhIZi0YZe33vIym2cPqygAyXEPfd/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: you did not add the video

Comment: you should use data template selector https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi Video link added. How I can fix this issue using data template selector?

Comment: @Sreejith Sree I notice that your sample contains your personal request address . I will not download it because of security policy . You would better delete it and create a new sample with static data . So I can only provide your some code snippet  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @ Shubham Tyagi . You could use **DataTemplateSelector** in your case .

#### in Code behind  create a custom DataTemplateSelector .

```
public class ChatDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate ReceiveTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate SendTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var obj = item as YourModel;

            string myUsername = "henry.pinto";
            string tweetUser = obj.tweetUser;
            if (myUsername == tweetUser)
            {
                return SendTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                return ReceiveTemplate;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### in Xaml

```
//...

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ReceiveTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame
                                FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                Rotation="180"
                                Padding="8"
                                Margin="0,8,0,8"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                HasShadow="False"
                                BorderColor="#f3db92"
                                BackgroundColor="#fdebb6"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                        <Label 
                                Text="{Binding tweetData}"
                                x:Name="tweetData"  
                                TextColor="Black"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                VerticalOptions="Center">
                           
                        </Label>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SendTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame
                                FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                Rotation="180"
                                Padding="8"
                                Margin="0,8,0,8"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                HasShadow="False"
                                BorderColor="Blue"
                                BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                        <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding tweetData}"
                                    x:Name="tweetData"  
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                    VerticalOptions="Center">                           
                        </Label>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:ChatDataTemplateSelector x:Key="ChatDataTemplateSelector"
                ReceiveTemplate="{StaticResource ReceiveTemplate}"
                SendTemplate="{StaticResource SendTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <StackLayout
        Orientation="Vertical"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}"
            //...
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChatDataTemplateSelector}" 
            >
            
            <ListView.Footer>
                <Label/>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>

      
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And you could remove the property like BgColor and BorderColor in the model . And remove the following code

```
string myUsername = "myusername";
string tweetUser = username in the message;
if (myUsername == tweetUser)
{
    tweet.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
}
else
{
    tweet.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
}
```